# VB: User Control Object Reference Error with Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, user-controls, object-reference

I'm working in Visual Studio 2010 with Visual Basic. I have a Windows Form and a User Control. On the User Control is a Datagridview, which is linked to a table, which is Public Shared.

When putting the User Control on the Windows Form I get the following Message, displayed where my Form was:

> **To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the**
>   **following errors must be resolved: Object reference not set to an**
>   **instance of an object.**
>
> at Fehlteilmanagement.CheckMultiple.CheckMultiple_Load(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in C:\Users\TO113808\Desktop\Fehlteilmanagement\Visual
>   Studio\Fehlteilmanagement\Fehlteilmanagement\Forms\CheckMultiple.vb:line
>   7 at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnCreateControl() at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl() at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection.Add(Control value) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.ControlCollection.Add(Control value) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner.DesignerControlCollection.Add(Control
>   c)

I know that it has something to do with my UserControl_Load Function, currently it looks like this:

```
        DGV_MultipleFT.DataSource = tableMultipleLinesFT
    DGV_MultipleFT.Columns("Neu").Visible = False

    For i = 0 To tableMultipleLinesFT.Rows.Count - 1
        If Not IsDBNull(tableMultipleLinesFT.Rows(i).Field(Of Boolean?)("Neu")) And tableMultipleLinesFT.Rows(i).Field(Of Boolean?)("Neu") = True Then
            DGV_MultipleFT.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.GreenYellow
        End If
```

If I delete the Changes in the DatagridView (DGV_MultipleFT) everything is fine. Even though i get the Error-Message, my Program compiles fine and works. But I want to ask what i can do about it.

If you want to have my Designer.vb I will post it, but if someone has an Idea, I would be very thankful.

Best Regards

Comment: Is the "TableMultipleLinesFT" Evaluated/existing prior to this load?

Comment: yes. it is created in my main function. after the table is created and filled, the userform is called via .ShowDialog

Comment: I would out a breakpoint there if I were you and see if anything is thrown. Everything else in that load function are things you can do in the properties of the datagridview, so they're existing, but this datatable's rows (Neu) or that column might not exist yet. Hence the  "not an instance of an object". One of these hasn't been evaluated yet, or is populated with null data.

Comment: I solved it by adding:

If Me.Designmode = True then
Goto LineEnde
End If

at the Beginning of the UserControl